# How to draw JavaScript charts that can cope with very high data volumes?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, charts

I tried but couldn't find a similar article so apologies if I missed any.

I am working on a project based on ASP.Net MVC4.

We need to draw charts (using AJAX, JavaScript) for ***very large volumes of data***.

E.g. we need to draw waveform charts that have 75,000+ data points.

We have so far implemented the solution with JQWidgets. This used to work fine with our initial tests, however the charts keep taking very long times to load when they are presented with large data volumes.

We have also tried HighCharts but it too started to slow down with large volumes of data (filtering out or summarizing data is not an option as of this time).

Please understand that we need to display large number of data as we need to visualize sensor generated waveforms.

I'm sure I'm not the only one who has faced this problem, so I was wondering if any of you could shed some light on the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [ZingChart library](http://www.zingchart.com) might interest you. ZingChart was specifically built for big data and offers some great features to ensure fast, stable renders.

[This demo](http://www.zingchart.com/features/big-data-charts/) easily renders 100k points in under a second, and if you're interested in comparisons, there's also the [ZingChart Vs. demo](http://www.zingchart.com/demos/zingchart-vs/) (note the warning in the top right).

I'm on the ZingChart team and we're here to answer any questions you might have about the library!

Comment: Chlorination many thanks. I will take a look at this.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to try high charts.

Get the required data and convert it into JSON and loaded the same using Dotnet.Highchart

Please find the reference : https://dotnethighcharts.codeplex.com/

EX:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts chart = new DotNet.Highcharts.Highcharts("chart")
        .SetXAxis(new XAxis
                    {
                        Categories = new[] { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec" }
                    })
        .SetSeries(new Series
                    {
                        Data = new Data(new object[] { 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4 })
                    });

    return View(chart);
}
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Highcharts seems a good contender but I really need to know the which library copes best when presented with **very large volumes** of data.
To be honest we wouldn't mind even the looks aren't that great.

Answer (score 1):

With such amount of data, you should probably think of loading your data on demand. I do not think any charting library will be able to cope with 75000 data points very well. The better approach I think would be to load the data on demand.

Comment: Hi Scripto, I agree. but the unfortunate problem is that these charts are waveforms. Individual data points don't really mean anything. Engineers need to look at the total shape of the wave. Our sensors generates upto 100,000 records (readings) per waveform :(